# ui-select with error loading "Module 'ui.select' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it."

Tags: angularjs, inject

I tried to use ui-select directive in my solution. I added the whole Github folder about ui-select in my solution. I also inject the 'ui.select' in my app.js. But when I run the solution, the following error is shown in the F12:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MetronicApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module oc.lazyLoad due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.select' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Comment: may be you included it before angularjs files. check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, using [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) instead of including the files directly.

for css:[https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.17.1/select.css]

for js :[https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.17.1/select.js]
include the about tags in your main index.html page, you no need to download the files and include them, [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) will provide the files.

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.17.1/select.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.17.1/select.js" async></script>
```

In app.js:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ui.select', 'ngSanitize']);
```

> Requirements for [ui.select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select):

- Angular >=1.2.18
- ngSanitize module
- jQuery ( optional for older browser support )
- Browser compatibility starting at Internet Explorer 8 and Firefox 3.6.
- Bootstrap/Select2/Selectize CSS as appropriate

Comment: This is more of a workaround than a proper solution and simply works around what was clearly an error injecting the files properly. There are too many Angular solutions that involve "use CDN" as a solution, bumping up the number of requests needed for an application without reason.

Comment: How can I use web pack module?

Answer (score 1):

Include the downloaded file path properly using script tags in your main index.html file and make sure that you injected the dependency properly as follow in your app.js file:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.select']);
```

(or)

Other way is to  use package managers:

You can use npm or bower installs

> npm install ui-select
>
> bower install angular-ui-select

and make sure that you injected the dependency properly

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.select']);
```

Comment: I have done both ways you mentioned, but there is still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Check your bower file.

If angularjs-ui-select not available add this line to your bower.json file

"angular-ui-select": "~0.18.1"

```
"version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-animate": "~1.5.3",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.5.3",
    "angular-touch": "~1.5.3",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.5.3",
    "angular-messages": "~1.5.3",
    "angular-aria": "~1.5.3",
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "angular-resource": "~1.5.3",
    "angular-route": "~1.5.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "~3.3.5",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.14.3",
    "malarkey": "yuanqing/malarkey#~1.3.1",
    "angular-toastr": "~1.5.0",
    "moment": "~2.10.6",
    "animate.css": "~3.4.0",
    "angular": "~1.5.3",
    "angular-daterangepicker": "^0.2.2",
    "angular-ui-select": "~0.18.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.5.3"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap-sass": {
      "main": [
        "assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss",
        "assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot",
        "assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg",
        "assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf",
        "assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff",
        "assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "angular": "~1.5.3"
  }
}
```